# How can <core-pages> get its height from the selected child?

Tags: polymer

I'm using Polymer web components, and I'm finding that the default height of the `core-pages` element is 0. I want it to depend on the height of its child elements, ideally the height of the selected child.

Here's an example page that demonstrates the issue ([live jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xuxowo/1/edit)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Before &lt;core-pages&gt; element</h1>
    <core-pages selected="0" block>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
      aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
      ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
      aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </core-pages>
    <h1>After &lt;core-pages&gt; element</h1>

    <script>
     // Uncomment this kludge to fix the layout.
     /* window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
     var selected = document.querySelector('core-selected');
     var height = window.getComputedStyle(selected).height;
     document.querySelector('core-pages').setAttribute('style', 'height:' + height);
     }); */
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

On my desktop Chrome 39, the trailing header overlaps the `core-pages` content (instead of appearing below it) because the `core-pages` element is given a height of 0 (which I believe is because the `core-pages` implementation uses absolute positioning on the child elements, but I could be wrong).

This can be "fixed" by giving the `core-pages` element an explicit height (such as with the commented javascript in the example), but this is undesirable and really should be triggered on reflow. It's ugly and doesn't align with Polymer's declarative emphasis.

Is there any elegant way to fit `core-pages` to its content so it lays out in an intuitive manner? I'm hoping there is some magical CSS or Polymer setting that will fix this.

Comment: No, not any non-kludgy way that doesn't involve trying to catch all the events that might affect the layout and executing javascript to correct the size.

Answer (score 2):

I came to the following workaround.

Say, we have a `core-pages` nesting my custom component `mudasobwa-custom`:

```
<core-pages selected="0" block>
  <mudasobwa-custom>CONTENT</mudasobwa-custom>  
</code-pages>
```

Let’s define a `PolymerExpression` like:

```
PolymerExpressions.prototype.elementSize = function(el) {
  var result = { w: 0, h: 0 };
  for (ch in el) {
    result.w += el[ch].offsetWidth;
    result.h += el[ch].offsetHeight;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Then we need to define a `computed` property on the `core-pages` descendant components (one might surround the content with “wrapper” component whether `core-pages` are nesting pure HTML elements, which is not my case; I have `mudasobwa-custom` component nested.)

```
<!--                         don’t forget to publish ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ -->
<polymer-element name="mudasobwa-custom" attributes="sizes ......
.......
Polymer({
.......
  needupdate: boolean,
  computed: {
    sizes: 'elementSize($, needupdate)'
  }
.......
```

Once the `needupdate` changes it’s value, the expression is to be recalculated (use it for explicit triggering.) The only think left is to bind `core-pages` width/height to this computed property:

```
<!--        use auto binding     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ -->           
<core-pages ... style="height:{{ sizes.h }}px;">
  <mudasobwa-custom sizes="{{ sizes }}">
```

This approach might look overengineered, but it requires the expression to be written only once and then you immediately yield an access to all the real widths/heights.

Live: http://plnkr.co/edit/U98IzTxUVUuEUuPbxNgF?p=preview

Hope it might help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<core-pages>` demo page ( https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-pages/demo.html ) they use also an explicit height to solve the problem, so I guess that it's the "official" way for now...

I'll try some CSS tricks latter to see if I can find a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 0):

If not needed the **absolute** positioning of the children, you can position them **relative** inside the core pages:

In your example:

```
core-pages > div {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEZjWd

Comment: Unfortunately the point of core-pages is to select and display one child. With relative positioning, core-pages controls child visibility but has blank areas where the unselected children are.